# Creating random image CoreGraphics leaking memory

Tags: ios, c, memory-leaks, core-graphics

In my program,
I have a method which create random generated imaged, 
Just notice with instruments that it׳s leaking memory but i׳m not sure why.

Here is the part that leaking:

```
int * getRandomImage(int width, int height) {
int * bytes = new int[height * width]; //this line is pointed by instruments

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        bytes[i * width + j] = arc4random();
    }
}

    return bytes
}





-(void) loadRandomImage {
const int height = 400;
const int width = 400;
int * bytes = getRandomImage(width, height);

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, bytes, width * height, NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

UIImage *newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

self.imageView.image = newUIImage;

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
```

Comment: And when is the array deleted?

Comment: @immibis Just added the method that makes the call to the part that leaking, you can see the provider getting released

Comment: Yeah, but I can't see the array you created getting deleted.

Comment: i need to make a free(bytes) after using it?

Comment: Do you know how to free something allocated with `new`?

Comment: @immibis by using free(object name) ?

Comment: Nope. Find a tutorial about `new`.

Comment: its a c++ array so should just go `delete[] bytes;` at the end of loadRandomImage